# What is he saying in this video 1:25-1:35

Tags: meaning, listening

I am watching 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6bZjzFC0jzU
he is saying " I bought all of my friendship Oli last night and I still have money in the bank"
when I check definition of Oli
Oli is a sweet guy and the one of the best people you can ever have in your life,
but I am not sure how to translate it into this sentence.

Comment: What he's saying is "I bought all of my friends [something that seems to start with an S] last night, and I still have money in the bank." The subtitles are definitely wrong—but he slurs the word or words so I can't determine what he actually bought his friends.

Comment: He's *potentially* saying [zeppole](http://www.olgasflavorfactory.com/recipes/favorites/zeppole-italian-doughnuts/) (Italian doughnuts) and just pronouncing it in a strange way. (But I wouldn't think those would be a huge expense.)

Comment: They aren't a huge expense. That is part of the prank. He is trying to 'impress' girls by boasting of what most people would think of as not impressive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting at 1:25, he says "I bought all of my friends Chipotle last night, and I still have money in the bank," where [Chipotle](https://www.chipotle.com/#) is an American restaurant which serves Mexican-style dishes. "Chipotle" here is understood to mean "food from Chipotle," as is fairly common with restaurant names.